# src/main.c:64:52: error: invalid operands to binary | (have ‘char *’ and ‘char *’)

Tags: c

How do i fix this error

```
src/main.c: In function ‘main’:
src/main.c:64:52: error: invalid operands to binary | (have ‘char *’ and ‘char *’)
   64 |                         if (strstr(argv[3], ".js") | strstr(argv[3], ".html")) {
      |                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                             |                        |
      |                             char *                   char *
```

i really like someone to help me to fix this

It Will Generate a file But It Did Not.

I really like someone to help me to fix this

Comment: Please add the code that causes the error to your question and explain what you're trying to do on that line. It looks like maybe you meant to use `||` instead.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to use the *logical* OR operator `||` instead of the bitwise OR operator `|`?

Answer (score 1):

`|` is the bitwise OR operator. `||` is the logical OR operator.

Here, you need the latter:

```
if (strstr(argv[3], ".js") || strstr(argv[3], ".html"))
```

See: [Operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/expressions#Operators).

Answer (score 0):

```c
    if (strstr(argv[3], ".js") || strstr(argv[3], ".html"))
```

or, more readably:

```c
    if (strstr(argv[3], ".js") != NULL || strstr(argv[3], ".html") != NULL)
```